# Java JFrame gui - Why won't the buttons show up?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've just started learning Swing/JFrame, basically making a GUI.
I've been doing Java for a month now, just using the console, making a sin/true or false games and it is pretty easy for me now.

I decided to take a further step, and I must say it's totally a pain, different logic.

That's what I've done so far:

Main.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Gui gui = new Gui();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                gui.createMyGui();
            }
         });
    }
}
```

gui.java

```
class Gui {

    protected JFrame j = new JFrame("My First window");
    protected JPanel p = new JPanel();
    protected Container c;

    public Gui() {
        j.setSize(500, 400);
        p.setSize(j.getSize());
        this.c = j.getContentPane();
    }

    public void createMyGui() {
        setButtons();
        setGuiBackground();
        j.setVisible(true);
        p.setVisible(true);
        this.c.add(p);
    }

    private void setGuiBackground() {
        this.c.setBackground(Color.green);
    }

    private void setButtons() {
        p.add(new JButton("Hey"));

    }
}
```

**Problem**

I can't really get the button to show up, people are telling me to use setBounds but I am not really sure on how to start as I can't even place a button there. I've tried searching about my problem, but no luck actually.

Basically what happens is a 500x400 green GUI opens, and that's it.

***Why won't the button show?***

Comment: First tip, don't use `setBounds`. [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) are designed to make your life easier :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*people are telling me to use setBounds*
Dont! Layout managers are the correct way to go.

Your problem is you add your buttons to the "p" panel, but you never add it (p panel) to the contentPane

Comment: Updated my code, new problem: Button shows in the center now, but the background absolutely turned white, why is this happening? How can I set my specific location to the button?

Comment: Thats because your "p" panel is "on top" of your contentPane
Either
1) Set the green color to the "p" panel OR
2) Make it transparent by using setOpaque(false)
And you really need to go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/